# Git, como cambiar la rama en remoto

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-commit

ayer creé un repo en gitlab y cada vez que hago un push a la rama en remoto me pide que haga un "merge request" me gustaria quitar esta opción y cada vez que haga un "Push" se integre en la rama.

En local quiero trabajar en "master" y en gitlab quiero tener la rama "master" también.

Si ejecuto estos comandos tengo este resultado

```
PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\proyecto1> git branch
* master

PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\proyecto1> git remote -v 
origin  https://gitlab.com/userTest/proyecto-pruebas.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/userTest/proyecto-pruebas.git (push)
```

Me gustaría saber que problema tengo y cual seria la solución más correcta.
Gracias

Comment: Por convencionalismo, "GitLab" no te va a dejar trabajar en la rama "master", lo más fácil es crearte una rama desde "master", porque no me suena que se puedan realizar "explicit commit" sobre "master".

Comment: no he usado gitlab aun... no te vale con un `git push --force` cuando estas en la rama master?

Comment: Tengo otros repos creado con anterioridad y si me deja hacerlo.

Comment: Seguro tienes la rama como protegida

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he encontrado, era configuración del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Settings ==> Repository ==> Default branch

Comment: El pantallazo deja ver la sección que hay que mirar: **Protected Braches**.